# For each in java for list interface

Tags: java, list, foreach

I have the following snippet

```
class Solution {


    public boolean canVisitAllRooms(List<List<Integer>> rooms) {
        int N = rooms.size();
        LinkedList<Integer> adj[] = new LinkedList[N];
        int i=0;
        for(List keys: rooms){
            for(Integer key: keys){
                adj[i].add(key);
                adj[key].add(i); 
            }
            i++;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I want to iterate using for-each only as I am trying to bring it into practice. I am getting error at the nested for loop saying object cannot be cast into Integer. I am unable to understand why it shouldnt work given rooms is a list of list of Integers.  Why does it takes the datatype as Object for elements of keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the generics argument for `List`:

```
for(List keys: rooms)
    ^^^^
```

```
for(List<Integer> keys: rooms)
```

---

See:

[- What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: Also I am not sure if it will accept ```adj[key].add(i);``` as ```i``` is a primitive.

Comment: Maybe it will autobox but I am not sure.